# COUNT of previous rows matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have table like:

```
KEY_NAME   START_DATE    END_DATE       
 X         01.01.2014    01.07.2014 
 X         01.02.2014    15.02.2014 
 X         01.03.2014   
 X         01.05.2014       
 X         01.07.2014       
 Y         01.01.2014       
 Y         06.01.2014    16.10.2014 
 Y         30.05.2014    17.09.2014 
 Y         04.08.2014
```

Starting with the 3rd order per `KEY_NAME`, I want to take the `START_DATE` and compare it with the `END_DATE` of previous rows with the same `KEY_NAME` 
(compare the `START_DATE` of 3rd `KEY_NAME` with `END_DATE`s of the 2nd and 1st row)

I need the number of previous rows where `END_DATE` is `NULL` or greater than the current `START_DATE`.

The output I want (column `COUNT`):

```
KEY_NAME     ORDER  Count   
X            3rd    1      -- 01.07.2014
X            4th    2      -- 01.07.2014 + null 
X            5th    3      -- 01.07.2014 + null + null
Y            3rd    2      -- null + 16.10.2014
Y            4th    3      -- null + 16.10.2014 + 17.09.2014
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You should at least tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: My feeling is that there is a better way to do whatever you are trying. However, regarding your question: If it is impossible with normal SQL statements, it for sure is possible from within a programming language which provides an adapter for your database server (most major server software is supported by most programming languages). If you don't want to use a programming language (PHP, Perl, Python, C etc.), you could implement your algorithm as an SP (stored procedure). In case you haven't heard about it yet: Imagine SPs as small programs which are running within your database.

Comment: here the problem is I do not know the number of counts in each KEY_NAMES. ( for ex. some have 50 date sets. ( so I should take >3 to 50)  There should be a way to write it with SQL.

Comment: Sounds as if this could be solved using window functions, however I am not 100% sure I understand what the output is you want.

Comment: @PeterLang I corrected it thanks.

Comment: @PeterLang yes I corrected it again. Thank you so much. I think you have idea about the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) to determine the rank per `key_name` and then select the number of rows that match your criteria.

I assumed that the sequence of your rows is determined by `start_date` but you can use any other `ORDER BY` when selecting `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Tested with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/533480/1).

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key_name ORDER BY start_date ) AS ord
  FROM t
)
SELECT key_name, ord,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM cte cte_prev
          WHERE cte_prev.key_name = cte.key_name
            AND cte_prev.ord < cte.ord
            AND ( cte_prev.end_date >= cte.start_date OR cte_prev.end_date IS NULL )
       ) AS cnt
  FROM cte
 WHERE cte.ord >= 3
 ORDER BY cte.key_name, cte.ord;
```